# IIRF / APACHE REWRITE REMOVE QUERY STRING FROM CONDITIONS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iirf

I have the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/events$ /pagebase.php?pbid=3627 [QSA,L,I]
RewriteRule ^/events-list$ /pagebase.php?pbid=3663 [QSA,L,I]
RewriteRule ^/bob2013$ /pagebase.php?pbid=3688 [QSA,L,I]
RewriteRule ^/contact-us$ /pagebase.php?pbid=3634 [QSA,L,I]
RewriteRule ^/detail$ /pagebase.php?pbid=3890 [QSA,L,I]
```

Which work great until I need to pass in query string.

So if I type

http://www.domain.com/events
It works perfectly.

But if I type in

http://www.domain.com/events?type=1

Then the rewrite fails because it does not match "events" anymore.

However if I remove the dollar sign then it works fine. The query string type is passed through correctly.

like so.

```
RewriteRule ^/events$ /pagebase.php?pbid=3627 [QSA,L,I]
```

However the issue with that is, if someone types the url for events list.

http://www.domain.com/events-list

The rewrite matches the "events" page displays that page.

Basically, I need to know how to get around this issue.

Comment: Have you tested this? Because RewriteRule only matches the path (excluding the querystring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to this is to order the rules accordingly: **specific rules before general rules**.

Since the first rule (without the `$` at the end) includes the second rule, put the second rule before the first one:

```
RewriteRule ^/events-list /pagebase.php?pbid=3663 [QSA,L,I]
RewriteRule ^/events      /pagebase.php?pbid=3627 [QSA,L,I]
```

Now any url starting with `/events-list` will be rewritten to `pbid=3663`.

However, in order to prevent urls like `/events-anything` from matching, it's better to include the matching of the *optional query string* in the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/events-list(\?.*)?$ /pagebase.php?pbid=3663 [QSA,L,I]
RewriteRule ^/events(\?.*)?$      /pagebase.php?pbid=3627 [QSA,L,I]
```